Can you use "line of thought" synonymously with "reasoning"?
I've always thought of the two as the same (I'm not a native though).
Though, recently I've read in a Dictionary it means "a specific way of thinking about a particular topic, concept, or problem" or "way of thinking". I'm not exactly sure what those two mean, though.
How can you use the phrase?

The metaphoric direction implication is stronger with line than with way, so it's more appropriate in contexts where the thought process being referenced is goal-oriented. For example, That line of thought / thinking should solve your problem. Less coherent mental processes (emotional reactions, etc.) don't work so well with line, but can be okay with way, because way doesn't so strongly imply goal-seeking. For example, If your girlfriend dumps you, try not to feel bitter. That way of thinking will only make things worse (not line there).

...put another way, a way of thinking could refer to someone "thinking in pictures", someone thinking lovingly about absent friends, etc. - not necessarily with any particular "purpose" in mind. But a line of thinking usually implies using thought constructively, in pursuit of a solution to a problem.

I'm not a native speaker either, so take this with a grain of salt, but when I read "line of thought" a similar sounding expression whose meaning correlates with that of "reasoning" instantly came to mind: "train of thought". Perhaps you confused the two? "line of thought" is a very similar compound of words, but as FumbleFingers explains, has a different meaning.

@kos: I didn't think of train, but obviously the metaphor there invokes railway lines - which always go somewhere. Sometime way evokes way to get there, but quite often it's just another word for type / sort / kind of thinking, which might not even have any clearly defined purpose. But sometimes a "train" of thought is all about moving from one idea to another related idea, even if there's no particular purpose. Like a stream of consciousness, that moves from one idea to another with no "control" or "guide" - just one thing making you think of another.

@kos I think that was what happened here.

As a fellow learner, I feel that. I get confused by similar things all the time :D

@FumbleFingers Can you name an example sentence with "line of thought" in relation to thinking in pictures?

@kos So, can you just say "what is your line of thought behind this chess move" instead of "what is your reasoning behind this chess move"?

No. "Line of thought" is something else altoghether. "Train of thought", albeit closer in meaning to "reasoning", wouldn't fit there either I think, at least not phrased the way you did. I'd find "what's the train of thought that led you to do this chess move" more fitting if you want to use "train of thought". But let's hear from FumbleFingers

@kos sorry, I actually meant to type "train of thought". I'm a little absent-minded right now.

siegmund freud: NO! I can't give an example sentence with "line / train of thought" in relation to thinking in pictures. The whole point of my comments, as @kos seems to recognize, is that the train and line metaphors don't work very well with the abstract concept of way, method, type, sort of thinking, because trains, (railway?) lines, etc. normally have to have a purpose, but "thinking in pictures" might just be aimless daydreaming. You don't need specialized knowledge of English to figure such things out - just reason for yourself how the metaphors work.

This is often the answer when we are asked "are these synonyms?" - no, but they could sometimes be interchangeable.
A 'thought' can mean an idea or opinion produced by thinking (or reasoning) but it can also mean one that occurs suddenly in the mind without reasoning or logic.
'Reasoning' is "the action of thinking about something in a logical, sensible way", so it describes the process of linking thoughts and evidence to conclusions.
So, thought and reasoning are two very different things.
However, the phrase you are asking about, "line of thought" may have an idiomatic meaning of its own, and this may be different depending on the dialect of English. The phrase is not actually found in Websters Dictionary (chiefly US); however the phrase "line of reasoning" is listed. Meanwhile, in the chiefly British English Cambridge Dictionary, there is a single entry for "line of reasoning, thinking, etc." with a single definition.

"line of thought" doesn't have a precise meaning.  Thought doesn't actually occur in a line, so "line" is being used figuratively there to mean something like "approach".  It is something more general than "reasoning", which refers to the logical flow of an argument.
